# Search records between two dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

Good afternoon, I am new to programming, I would like to ask you for help with the following:
I have two DataFrames df1 and df2

df1 is composed of the following registers:

| ID | Nombre | Teléfono |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | ANTONIO | 345 |
| C0002 | LAURA | 326 |
| C0003 | CAMILO | 289 |
| C0004 | JOSE | 245 |

df2 is made up of these other registers:

| ID | Nombre | Teléfono |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | ANTONIO | 345 |
| C0002 | LAURA | 326 |
| C0003 | CAMILO | 289 |
| C0004 | JOSE | 245 |
| C0005 | NATALIA | 345 |
| C0006 | ERIKA | 326 |
| C0007 | LINA | 289 |
| C0008 | CRISTINA | 245 |

I want to get a third df3 in this way which only contains the records where ID is unique

| ID | Nombre | Teléfono | `` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0005 | NATALIA | 345 |  |
| C0006 | ERIKA | 326 |  |
| C0007 | LINA | 289 |  |
| C0008 | CRISTINA | 245 |  |

I use the isin() method

x=df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)

but it shows the following, I would like to know how I can take the records that are false and show their information:
0  True
1  True
2  True
3  True
4  False
5  False
6  False
7  False

I need to get this result:

| ID | Nombre | Teléfono |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C0005 | NATALIA | 345 |
| C0006 | ERIKA | 326 |
| C0007 | LINA | 289 |
| C0008 | CRISTINA | 245 |

Answer (score 1):

Combine [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with the unary `~` [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) to invert the boolean values, and use the series to select from `df2`:

```
df2[~df2.ID.isin(df1.ID)]

      ID    Nombre  Teléfono
4  C0005   NATALIA       345
5  C0006     ERIKA       326
6  C0007      LINA       289
7  C0008  CRISTINA       245
```